# Hide Shopify shop behind a paywall

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to create a shop that requires paid membership to use. I love what Shopify has to offer. Is it possible (with their API or by using an existing app) to force users to purchase a membership before they can access the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is trivial to do if you can setup a subdomain and use Stripe. No one gets into Shopify without having an account, and no one gets an account except through you. Once they buy a membership via your Stripe form, you create their Shopify account, and send them their invite to use the Shop.

Nothing could be simpler...

Comment: So just to make sure: if a user purchases a subscription, I can create an account for them programmatically, and if they already have an account, I can redirect automatically to my Shopify? I can also set my Shopify shop to block users without accounts, and I can delete user accounts when subscriptions run out? If all this is true then I guess I'm good to go! Sorry I'm being so particular, I'm just having a hard time with Shopify's docs.

Comment: Additionally, will a user have to login twice? Once at my paywall and once on the Shopify site? Or can I log a user into my Shopify site programmatically?

Comment: They should not even need to ever hit your paywall unless they have no Shopify account... You do not log anyone into your shop. They login using their Shopify customer account details.